# Xcode - TagTextField Component: Dynamically resize superview to fit subviews

Tags: xcode, uiview, uibutton, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I have created a UIView with two subviews; a uibutton and uitextfield. The button is on the left of the text field and constraints determine the horizontal position for the text field automatically. Similarly the UITextfield expands to fit it's text content dynamically using constraints too.

I want the superview (UIView) to expand to the width of the both controls automatically but can't find a way to do so. Could someone suggest a way to create constraints for a superview so it adjusts when it's subviews change size?

Thanks
D

**Update**
Heya, So I am trying to create a Tag-Textfield like the following, where the user can enter text on the right or press a button on the left to prompt a modal popover list:
[image: Search filter type - In Mail on OSX]

Comment: does one of the subview expend dynamically, or the width is set from the start?\

Comment: Both subviews adjust dynamically but have a minimum size from initialisation

Comment: you need to get to the point that you have constraints that "raps" all the subViews on the vertical & hierarchical exes

Comment: Hi, can you please add image of storyboard for this particular view as it will be helpful. As it will exactly display the way you need to display the view in different devices.